# Creating a simple web application with Eclipse, Java, Gradle, Wildfly, Hibernate JPA, Spring and Angular

Tags: java, angular, hibernate, spring-boot

I've created several projects in Eclipse following online examples on how to create simple web applications with a combination of various technologies. I'm using Java 11 at the moment, Eclipse IDE (version 4.12.0), Wildfly 17, Gradle 5.6, Hibernate 5.4.4 and JSFs with Primefaces 7.0. Everything works well together but I want more.

Is there a simple way I can transform my EJB project into an EJB using Spring framework with Hibernate and properly exposing my methods to the UI with RESTful web services? After that I want to replace my JSFs with Angular MVC.

I find it hard to get proper information on the web for my magic combo.

**My Eclipse project structure is:**

1. DEMO - my main project (EAR)
2. DemoCORE - nested backend project (EJB)
3. DemoUI - nested frontend project (WAR)

[image]

**My EJB dependencies:**

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '8.0'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.4.4.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.0.17.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '5.4.4.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-annotations', version: '3.5.6-Final'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot', version: '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-rest', version: '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-commons', version: '2.2.3.RELEASE'
}
```

With these dependencies set up, I can call Spring methods anywhere in my EJB project.

**A simple interface for the Users DAO:**

```
@Remote
public interface UsersDAORemote {
    public User create(User user);
    public List<User> create(List<User> users);
    public User update(User user);
    public List<User> update(List<User> users);
    public void remove(User user);
    public void remove(List<User> users);
    public void removeById(Integer id);
    public void removeByIdList(List<Integer> idList);
    public User getUserById(Integer id);
    public List<User> getUserList();
    public List<User> getUserListByIdList(List<Integer> idList);
    public List<User> getUserListByCategoryId(Integer id);
    public List<User> getUserListByCategoryIdList(List<Integer> idList);
    public List<User> getUserListByGroupId(Integer id);
    public List<User> getUserListByGroupIdList(List<Integer> idList);
    public boolean getUserAuthentication(String username, String password);
}
```

**A Users DAO implementation:**

```
@RunAs(value = "")
@PermitAll
@Stateless
public class UsersDAO implements UsersDAOLocal, UsersDAORemote {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public User create(User user) {
        em.persist(user);
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> create(List<User> users) {
        List<User> uList = new ArrayList<User>();
        for (User u : users) {
            em.persist(u);
            uList.add(u);
        }
        if (uList.isEmpty()) {
            return new ArrayList<User>();
        }
        return uList;
    }

    @Override
    public User update(User user) {
        em.merge(user);
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> update(List<User> users) {
        List<User> uList = new ArrayList<User>();
        for (User u : users) {
            em.merge(u);
            uList.add(u);
        }
        if (uList.isEmpty()) {
            return new ArrayList<User>();
        }
        return uList;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(User user) {
        em.remove(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(List<User> users) {
        for (User u : users) {
            em.remove(u);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeById(Integer id) {
        em.remove(getUserById(id));
    }

    @Override
    public void removeByIdList(List<Integer> idList) {
        for (Integer id : idList) {
            if (getUserById(id) != null) {
                removeById(id);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserById(Integer id) {
        if (id != null) {
            return em.find(User.class, id);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getUserList() {
        return em.createNamedQuery("getUsersList", User.class).getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getUserListByIdList(List<Integer> idList) {
        List<User> uList = new ArrayList<User>();
        User u = null;
        if (!idList.isEmpty()) {
            for (Integer id : idList) {
                u = getUserById(id);
                if (u != null) {
                    uList.add(u);
                }
            }
        }
        if (uList.isEmpty()) {
            return new ArrayList<User>();
        }
        return uList;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getUserListByCategoryId(Integer id) {
        TypedQuery<User> query = em.createNamedQuery("getUsersListByCategoryId", User.class);
        query.setParameter("id_category", id);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getUserListByCategoryIdList(List<Integer> idList) {
        List<User> result = new ArrayList<User>();
        for (Integer id : idList) {
            if (id != null) {
                result.addAll(getUserListByCategoryId(id));
            }
        }
        if (result.isEmpty()) {
            return new ArrayList<User>();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getUserListByGroupId(Integer id) {
        TypedQuery<User> query = em.createNamedQuery("getUsersListByGroupId", User.class);
        query.setParameter("id_category", id);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getUserListByGroupIdList(List<Integer> idList) {
        List<User> result = new ArrayList<User>();
        for (Integer id : idList) {
            if (id != null) {
                result.addAll(getUserListByGroupId(id));
            }
        }
        if (result.isEmpty()) {
            return new ArrayList<User>();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getUserAuthentication(String username, String password) {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("authenticateUser");
        query.setParameter("uName", username);
        query.setParameter("uPwd", password);
        return (boolean) query.getSingleResult();
    }
    
}
```

**And my entity:**

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "getUsersList",  
        query = "select u from User u"  
    ),
    @NamedQuery(name = "getUsersListByCategoryId",  
        query = "select u from User u where u.categoryId = :categoryId"  
    ),
    @NamedQuery(name = "getUsersListByGroupId",  
        query = "select u from User u where u.groupId = :groupId"  
    ),
    @NamedQuery(name = "authenticateUser",  
        query = "select case when (count(u) > 0) then true else false end from User u where u.uName = :uName and u.uPwd = :uPwd"  
    )
})

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7927104765389722941L;
    
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false) private Integer id;
    @NotNull @Column(name = "id_category", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "int default 0") private Integer categoryId;
    @NotNull @Column(name = "id_group", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "int default 0") private Integer groupId;
    @NotNull @Length(max=64) @Column(name = "username", nullable = false) private String uName;
    @NotNull @Length(max=128) @Column(name = "password", nullable = false) private String uPwd;
    
    
    @NotNull @Column(name = "add_datetime", nullable = false) private Date add_datetime;
    @NotNull @Column(name = "add_uid", nullable = false) private Integer add_uid;
    @Null @Column(name = "modify_datetime", nullable = true) private Date modify_datetime;
    @Null @Column(name = "modify_uid", nullable = true) private Integer modify_uid;
    
    public Integer getId() { return id; }
    
    public Integer getCategoryId() { return categoryId; }
    public void setCategoryId(Integer id) { this.categoryId = id; }
    
    public String getUsername() { return uName; }
    public void setUsername(String uName) { this.uName = uName; }
    
    public String getPwd() { return uPwd; }
    public void setPwd(String uPwd) { this.uPwd = uPwd; }
    
    public Date getAdd_datetime() { return add_datetime; }
    public void setAdd_datetime(Date add_datetime) { this.add_datetime = add_datetime; }
    public Integer getAdd_uid() { return add_uid; }
    public void setAdd_uid(Integer add_uid) { this.add_uid = add_uid; }
    public Date getModify_datetime() { return modify_datetime; }
    public void setModify_datetime(Date modify_datetime) { this.modify_datetime = modify_datetime; }
    public Integer getModify_uid() { return modify_uid; }
    public void setModify_uid(Integer modify_uid) { this.modify_uid = modify_uid; }
}
```

**UPDATE (2020-01-05):**

I have followed this tutorial: https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angular-example and implemented the following classes in my EJB project.

**UserController.java**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://192.168.0.101:8080", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/apiUsers"})
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @PostMapping
    public User create(@RequestBody User user){
        return userService.createUser(user);
    }
    
    @GetMapping(path = {"/getUsersById/{id}"})
    public User getUserById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        return userService.getUserById(id);
    }
    
    @PutMapping
    public User update(@RequestBody User user){
        return userService.update(user);
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping(path ={"/delById/{id}"})
    public void delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        userService.removeById(id);
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping
    public void delete(@RequestBody User user) {
        userService.remove(user);
    }
    
    @GetMapping(path ={"/getAll"})
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return userService.getUserList();
    }
    
    @GetMapping(path ={"/getByCategroyId/{idCategory}"})
    public List<User> getUsersListByIdCategory(@PathVariable("idCategory") Long id) {
        return userService.getUserListByCategoryId(id);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/getByIdCategoryList/{idList}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<User> getUsersListByIdCategoryList(@PathVariable("idList") List<Long> id) {
        return userService.getUserListByCategoryIdList(id);
    }
    
    @GetMapping(path ={"/getByIdGroup/{idGroup}"})
    public List<User> getUsersListByIdGroup(@PathVariable("idGroup") Long id) {
        return userService.getUserListByGroupId(id);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/getByIdGroupList/{idList}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<User> getUsersListByIdGroupList(@PathVariable("idList") List<Long> id) {
        return userService.getUserListByGroupIdList(id);
    }
    
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{
    public List<User> findByIdCategory(Long idCategory);
    public List<User> findByIdGroup(Long idCategory);
    public Optional<User> findByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password);
}
```

**UserService.java**

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    public User createUser(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
        return user;
    }
    
    public User update(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
        return user;
    }
    
    public List<User> update(List<User> users) {
        userRepository.saveAll(users);
        return users;
    }
    
    public User remove(User user) {
        User u = getUserById(user.getId());
        if(u != null){
            userRepository.delete(u);
        }
        return u;
    }
    
    public void remove(List<User> users) {
        userRepository.deleteAll(users);
    }
    
    public User removeById(Long id) {
        User user = getUserById(id);
        if(user != null){
            userRepository.delete(user);
        }
        return user;
    }
    
    public void removeByIdList(List<Long> idList) {
        for (Long id : idList) {
            userRepository.deleteById(id);
        }
    }
    
    public User getUserById(Long id) {
        Optional<User> optional = userRepository.findById(id);
        return optional.orElseGet(null);
    }
    
    public List<User> getUserList() {
        return (List<User>) userRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    public List<User> getUserListByIdList(List<Long> idList) {
        List<User> result = new ArrayList<User>();
        if (!idList.isEmpty()) {
            for (Long id : idList) {
                Optional<User> u = userRepository.findById(id);
                if (u.isPresent()) {
                    result.add(u.get());
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    public List<User> getUserListByCategoryId(Long id) {
        return userRepository.findByIdCategory(id);
    }
    
    public List<User> getUserListByCategoryIdList(List<Long> idList) {
        List<User> result = new ArrayList<User>();
        if (!idList.isEmpty()) {
            for (Long id : idList) {
                List<User> u = userRepository.findByIdCategory(id);
                if (!u.isEmpty()) {
                    result.addAll(u);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    public List<User> getUserListByGroupId(Long id) {
        return userRepository.findByIdGroup(id);
    }
    
    public List<User> getUserListByGroupIdList(List<Long> idList) {
        List<User> result = new ArrayList<User>();
        if (!idList.isEmpty()) {
            for (Long id : idList) {
                List<User> u = userRepository.findByIdGroup(id);
                if (!u.isEmpty()) {
                    result.addAll(u);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    public boolean getUserAuthentication(String username, String password) {
        Optional<User> u = userRepository.findByUsernameAndPassword(username, password);
        if (u.isPresent()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I have successfully deployed the EAR on my Wildfly app server but I have no clue how to test if the service is actually working or not before I start creating the GUI. I've made several GET requests with the Postman app locally like this http://192.168.0.101:8080/DEMO/apiUsers/getAll and all I got were 404 errors.

I have also tried rewriting the UserController as described on this site:
http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-restful-web-services-crud-example-resttemplate/

**UserController.java**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://192.168.0.101:8080", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/apiUsers"})
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/createUser/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(@RequestBody User user, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
        System.out.println("Creating User " + user.getUsername());
 
        if (userService.doesUserExist(user)) {
            System.out.println("A User with name " + user.getUsername() + " already exist");
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
 
        userService.createUser(user);
 
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/getUserById/{id}").buildAndExpand(user.getId()).toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    
    @GetMapping(path = {"/getUserById/{id}"})
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUserById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        System.out.println("Fetching User with id " + id);
        User user = userService.getUserById(id);
        if (user == null) {
            System.out.println("User with id " + id + " not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateUser/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody User user) {
        System.out.println("Updating User " + id);
         
        User currentUser = userService.getUserById(id);
         
        if (currentUser==null) {
            System.out.println("User with id " + id + " not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        
        currentUser.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        currentUser.setIdCategory(user.getIdCategory());
        currentUser.setIdGroup(user.getIdGroup());
        currentUser.setPwd(user.getPwd());
         
        userService.update(currentUser);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(currentUser, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/delById/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<User> deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        System.out.println("Fetching & Deleting User with id " + id);
 
        User user = userService.getUserById(id);
        if (user == null) {
            System.out.println("Unable to delete. User with id " + id + " not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
 
        userService.removeById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAll/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers() {
        List<User> users = userService.getUserList();
        if(users.isEmpty()){
            return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getByCategroyId/{idCategory}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsersListByIdCategory(@PathVariable("idCategory") Long id) {
        System.out.println("Fetching List<User> by category with id " + id);
        List<User> users =  userService.getUserListByCategoryId(id);
        if(users.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Unable to fetch list. List<User> by category " + id + " not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);  
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getByIdCategoryList/{idList}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsersListByIdCategoryList(@PathVariable("idList") List<Long> idList) {
        System.out.println("Fetching List<User> by category with id " + idList);
        List<User> users =  userService.getUserListByCategoryIdList(idList);
        if(users.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Unable to fetch list. List<User> by category list not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);  
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getByIdGroup/{idGroup}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsersListByIdGroup(@PathVariable("idGroup") Long id) {
        System.out.println("Fetching List<User> by category with id " + id);
        List<User> users =  userService.getUserListByGroupId(id);
        if(users.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Unable to fetch list. List<User> by category " + id + " not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);  
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getByIdGroupList/{idList}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsersListByIdGroupList(@PathVariable("idList") List<Long> idList) {
        System.out.println("Fetching List<User> by category with id " + idList);
        List<User> users =  userService.getUserListByGroupIdList(idList);
        if(users.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Unable to fetch list. List<User> by category list not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);  
    }
    
}
```

I still get the 404.

I have probably missed something in the coding process or maybe even app server settings (Wildfly 17).

Comment: Edited as requested.

Comment: have you tried any other endpoint besides getAll? keep in mind that if you declare the request mapping value as "/getAll/" and then you try to reach just "/getAll" (note the missing backslash) it won't work

Comment: I have tried other endpoints as well. None of them work. They all return 404. I know about the slashes for that particular one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer that will convert your EJBs into Spring code directly. 
But considering you have existing database, you can import that DB into WaveMaker, we generate Spring code and REST API for CRUD operations. [See this how to article](https://www.wavemaker.com/learn/app-development/services/database-services/database-services).
Named queries you already have [can be written as queries](https://www.wavemaker.com/learn/app-development/services/database-services/working-with-queries) on DB and WaveMaker will generate REST API to invoke these queries too.
For CRUD actions creating UI with List,Forms,Tables in WaveMaker is a cinch. We generate Angular code for the UI.
You can evaluate the tool for free.